# Mysql trigger after update insert into another table with condition

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

Below code for my trigger after **update table** `student_approve` insert data to table notification but **occurs error at line no 5**

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS  `student_approve`;
CREATE TRIGGER `student_approve` AFTER UPDATE ON `student_info` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
IF NEW.student_approval LIKE '1' THEN
INSERT INTO `notifications` (user_to_notify,who_fired_event,noti_event_id)VALUES(NEW.registered_by,1,2);
END IF;
END
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LIKE cannot be used in a simple comparison it's only supported in a WHERE clause. Don't forget to change the delimiter as well.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS  `student_approve`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `student_approve` AFTER UPDATE ON `student_info` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
   IF NEW.student_approval = '1' THEN
     INSERT INTO `notifications` (user_to_notify,who_fired_event,noti_event_id) VALUES(NEW.registered_by,1,2);
   END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Would fix the syntax error but I of course we cannot tell if the result is what you want.

Comment: still same error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5 "

Comment: This syntax is correct. have you forgotten to set the delimiter?

Comment: i set delimiter also if i removed if condition then trigger created but with if condition give error

Comment: Then the only conclusion to be reached is that you haven't posted your exact code.

Comment: i added screenshot

Comment: as I have mentioned in my comment and as shown in my answer. You need to use a delimiter other than `;` you haven't done so. Look again at my answer please

Comment: Glad to have helped

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132477/discussion-between-nileshsinh-rathod-and-e4c5).