# MySQL: how to update a table based on changes to another table with trigger or stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers, phpmyadmin

Because of the limitation of a wordpress plugin I am using I cannot update tables from the website when they are created from `JOIN` statement. And I cannot use a view (plugin has problem updating views: https://wpdatatables.com/documentation/front-end-editing/creating-editable-tables/ (MySQL Views cannot be edited properly – only one of the underlying tables can be edited if you pass the proper ID)) So I created a bigger table with data of all tables. But I want that when a website user edits a field in this table then the update should be reflected to the "joined" tables.

For example I have these tables (in reality the tables have ~20 fields and the big one has ~50 fields):

Students:

```
+----+------+-----+
| id | name | age |
+----+------+-----+
|  1 | John |  34 |
|  2 | Mary |  21 |
+----+------+-----+
```

Courses:

```
+----+--------+----------+
| id | course | semester |
+----+--------+----------+
|  1 | math   | 1st      |
|  2 | geo    | 2n       |
+----+--------+----------+
```

Registrations:

```
+----+------------+------+-----+-----------+--------+----------+
| id | student_id | name | age | course_id | course | semester |
+----+------------+------+-----+-----------+--------+----------+
|  1 |          1 | John |  34 |         1 | math   | 1st      |
|  2 |          2 | Mary |  21 |         2 | geo    | 2n       |
+----+------------+------+-----+-----------+--------+----------+
```

So when user for example a user edits the name of a student then the edit has to be made both to the `Registrations` table and to the `Students`. But it has to be done via a `trigger` or a `stored procedure` in `phpmyadmin` because I dont want to change the functionality of the wordpress plugin. How I can create this kind of trigger or stored procedure in `Students` or `Courses`?

Comment: What exactly prevents you from creating a trigger before uodate on registration? in one trigger you can update multiple tables and you can of course define different trigger for the same table. like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41502596/mysql-trigger-after-update-insert-into-another-table-with-condition

Comment: I didn't understand the reason, why you don't use a clean design and remove the `name` and `course` columns from the `registration` table.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel because of the plugin's limitation. I cant update data from joined tables. If I could then I would use a pivot table with the ids only...

Comment: Sorry.. I don't get it. But here is the answer: [CREATE TRIGGER Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html)